# Ambiguous access

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do multiple-inherited functions with same name but different signatures not get treated as overloaded functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not-g)

I am getting an error:

```
ambiguous access of 'attach'
    could be the 'attach' in base 'A::A1'
    or could be the 'attach' in base 'B::B1'
```

This is the code:

```
class A
{
public:
    class A1
    {
    public:
        virtual void attach( A & a ) { }
    };
public:
};

class B
{
public:
    class B1
    {
    public:
        virtual void attach( B & b ) { }
    };
public:
};

class C : public A::A1, public B::B1
{
public:
    C(){ }
};

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    c.attach( a );
    c.attach( b );
}
```

I understand the error.  The compiler is confused, it wants scope:

```
c.A::A1::attach( a );
c.B::B1::attach( b );
```

That syntax is horrible.  I can define the attach methods in C, and *now* the compiler gets it, but I don't want to have to define all of these attach methods:

```
class C : public A::A1, public B::B1
{
public:
    C(){ }
void attach( A & a ) { A::A1::attach(a); }
void attach( B & b ) { B::B1::attach(b); }
};
```

Can anyone explain to me why the compiler is confused about 'attach' when it is clear (in my mind) which 'attach' should be used?  Can anyone offer a solution that does not require scoping?

**UPDATE**: updated the scope in my second C example, e.g. `A::A1::attach(a)`

**UPDATE**: when investigating the duplicate noted below, I came across the solution:

```
class C : public A::A1, public B::B1
{
public:
    using A::A1::attach;
    using B::B1::attach;
public:
    C(){ }
};
```

In my 18 years as a c++ programmer, I've never had to use 'using' like that.  I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: @Xeo: I don't think that's a duplicate- he wants to know *why*.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ehm.. what is the first word in my question title?

Comment: @Xeo was correct.  It is a duplicate.  The answer is there.  I updated the question to contain the (rather surprising) solution.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is to avoid the Fragile Base Class problem. Consider what would happen if this worked as you expected- and then A::A1 adds an overload taking a B::B1 reference. Suddenly, *all* your call sites are ambiguous- even though you didn't change anything. This is *even* true if the overload is private.

Of course, in my opinion, this is highly pointless, since there are a million *other* ways you can break your derived classes and other problems. But that's the apparent rationale.

Answer (score 2):

You can write this in class C:

```
using A::A1::attach;
using B::B1::attach;
```

Instead of

```
void attach( A & a ) { A::A1::attach(a); }
void attach( B & b ) { B::B1::attach(b); }
```