# Overload resolution with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

Consider following example ([link to ideone](https://ideone.com/lH2fCd)):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
public:
    void doit(){}
};

class Base2
{
    void doit(int x){}
};

class Derrived : public Base1, public Base2
{
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
   Derrived d;
   d.doit(); // doesn't work - error: request for member ‘doit’ is ambiguous
   d.::Base1::doit(); //works
   return 0;
}
```

Both Base1 and Base2 have member function doit with different input arguments, so overloads in theory should be resolved automatically.
However, attempt to call 
d.doit();
fails with error

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:36:6: error: request for member ‘doit’ is ambiguous
    d.doit(); // doesn't work - error: request for member ‘doit’ is ambiguous
      ^
prog.cpp:18:7: note: candidates are: void Base2::doit(int)
  void doit(int x)
       ^
prog.cpp:6:10: note:                 void Base1::doit()
     void doit()
          ^
```

and I have to type d.::Base1::doit(); to make it work.

Why compiler is unable to resolve which function to call without me explicitly specifying it? Is it expected behavior??

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not?rq=1?

Comment: @mtripp100 - Yes, sorry, I couldn't find other question, but looks like exact duplicate. Should I just delete it, or mark as duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.

Before overload resolution, *name lookup* is performed, which has its own set of rules. It has to find an unambiguous name and there isn't one in your case.