# C++ inheritance+overloading

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
struct X{ 
    void stream(int){} 
};
struct Y : public X{
    void stream(int, int){}
};

int main()
{
    Y y;
    y.stream(2);
}
```

Why `X::stream(int)` is not inherited?

Or it is hided with `Y::stream(int, int)`. If so, why it hidden, not overridden?

Comment: A derived class member function hides base class member functions of the same name regardless of signature. There must be a dup somewhere...

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not?rq=1

Comment: @chris But there is no ambiguous calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names in derived classes do indeed hide identical names in base classes. This is deliberate. If the base class changes, you don't suddenly and silently want to see a different overload set in your derived class.

To unhide base names explicitly, add `using X::stream;` into your derived class.