# Template instantiation ambiguity

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with a [templated implementation](https://github.com/PerMalmberg/CppFSM) of an FSM and am encountering an ambiguity as follows:

```
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/FSM.h: In instantiation of ‘void fsm::FSM<FSMBaseState>::Event(std::unique_ptr<EventType>) [with EventType = AddEvent; FSMBaseState = EventBaseState]’:
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/test.cpp:83:44:   required from here
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/FSM.h:59:4: error: request for member ‘Event’ is ambiguous
    myCurrent->Event( std::move( event ) );
    ^
In file included from /home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/FSM.h:12:0,
                 from /home/permal/code/FSM/Test/test.cpp:8:
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/EventReceiver.h:15:15: note: candidates are: void fsm::EventReceiver<EventType>::Event(std::unique_ptr<_Tp>) [with EventType = SubtractEvent]
  virtual void Event( std::unique_ptr<EventType> event ) = 0;
               ^
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/EventReceiver.h:15:15: note:                 void fsm::EventReceiver<EventType>::Event(std::unique_ptr<_Tp>) [with EventType = AddEvent]
In file included from /home/permal/code/FSM/Test/test.cpp:8:0:
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/FSM.h: In instantiation of ‘void fsm::FSM<FSMBaseState>::Event(std::unique_ptr<EventType>) [with EventType = SubtractEvent; FSMBaseState = EventBaseState]’:
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/test.cpp:91:50:   required from here
/home/permal/code/FSM/Test/../FSM/dist/include/FSM.h:59:4: error: request for member ‘Event’ is ambiguous
    myCurrent->Event( std::move( event ) );
```

So my question is why the compiler cannot choose the correct option even though it spells out that there are two possible candidates, one of which is the correct one.

I hope the code below is enough to show the problem, the rest is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/PerMalmberg/CppFSM)

This is the class and method where the ambiguity occurs:

```
template<typename FSMBaseState>
class FSM
{
public:
    ...

    template<typename EventType>
    void Event( std::unique_ptr<EventType> event )
    {
        if( HasState() )
        {
            // This way of calling causes ambiguous method lookup during template instantiation
            myCurrent->Event( std::move( event ) );

            // casting to the correct type works, but is it really needed?
            // auto* s = myCurrent.get();
            // static_cast<EventReceiver<EventType>*>( s )->Event( std::move( event ) );
        }
    }

};
```

The above method is called either as `fsm.Event( std::make_unique<AddEvent>() );` or `fsm.Event( std::make_unique<SubractEvent>() );`

`myCurrent` in the above Event()-method is an instance of the following class:

```
class EventBaseState
: public fsm::BaseState<EventBaseState>,
      public fsm::EventReceiver<AddEvent>,
      public fsm::EventReceiver<SubtractEvent>
{
public:
EventBaseState( const std::string& name, fsm::FSM<EventBaseState>& fsm ) :
        BaseState( name, fsm )
{}

};
```

where `EventReceiver` is defined as follows:

```
template<typename EventType>
class EventReceiver
{
public:
    virtual void Event( std::unique_ptr<EventType> event ) = 0;
};
```

## Update

Looking at things from a new angle, I ended up with a pure virtual functions for the `Event<T>(...)` methods, which is actually what I really wanted as the `EventBaseState` class was supposed to be abstract.

```
class EventBaseState
    : public fsm::BaseState<EventBaseState>,
      public fsm::EventReceiver<AddEvent>,
      public fsm::EventReceiver<SubtractEvent>
{
public:
    EventBaseState( const std::string& name, fsm::FSM<EventBaseState>& fsm ) :
            BaseState( name, fsm )
    {}

    virtual void Event( std::unique_ptr<AddEvent> event ) override = 0;
    virtual void Event( std::unique_ptr<SubtractEvent> event ) override = 0;
};
```

Of course, the solution provided by [Chajnik-U](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6908891/chajnik-u) works too.

Comment: `myCurrent->Event( std::move( event ) );` This is the important line. What's the type of `myCurrent` and of `event`? How exactly are those two variables declared in the function that calls `myCurrent->Event( std::move( event ) );`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It's in the question: `myCurrent` is `EventBaseState` and `event` is `std::unique_ptr<AddEvent>` or `std::unique_ptr<SubtractEvent>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods of the base classes do not participate in "cross class" overload when called via derived class instance.
You have to place

```
using EventReceiver<AddEvent>::Event;
using EventReceiver<SubtractEvent>::Event;
```

inside `EventBaseState` to force both methods to be visible by overload.
For more details from the point of view of the standard (with simplified example) please see here:

[Why do multiple-inherited functions with same name but different signatures not get treated as overloaded functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not)

Comment: You're likely correct and I will mark this as the answer when I've tried it out. I must say that the compiler message really leads you down the wrong path - it actually states that there are two candidates available, but then ignores them.