# Why are methods with different signatures "ambiguous" when they come from different base classes?

Tags: c++, gcc, multiple-inheritance, clang++

Consider the following example of a class `super` that inherits from two base classes that each provide a method with same name, but different signatures:

```cpp
struct a {};
struct b {};

class foo {
public:
  void method(a const &) {}
};

class bar {
public:
  void method(b const &) {}
};

class super : public foo, public bar {
public:
  void something()
  {
    method(b {}); // <- Ambiguous?
  }
};
```

This fails to compile with GCC and clang due to the compiler claiming that the call to `method` is ambiguous:

```
overload.cpp: In member function ‘void super::something()’:
overload.cpp:18:5: error: reference to ‘method’ is ambiguous
   18 |     method(b {});
      |     ^~~~~~
overload.cpp:11:8: note: candidates are: ‘void bar::method(const b&)’
   11 |   void method(b const &) {}
      |        ^~~~~~
overload.cpp:6:8: note:                 ‘void foo::method(const a&)’
    6 |   void method(a const &) {}
      |        ^~~~~~
```

It looks like it is perfectly decidable which method to call depending on the method signature.

Is this failure to resolve the method call a compiler issue or is this behavior mandated by the C++ standard?

Our current workaround is to place `using foo::method; using bar::method;` declarations in `class super`. With that the compiler is able to resolve calls to `method` without problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not