# C++ : Inheriting from lambdas, overload resolution "quirk"

Tags: c++, inheritance, lambda, overload-resolution, using-declaration

Why is the using-declaration inside `struct S` necessary?

`struct S` inherits from both `l1`'s and `l2`'s types, which means their respective `operator()`s are considered when calling `s(123)`. This is corroborated by the fact that, *once I remove* `using`, gcc tells me the **"request for member ‘operator()’ is ambiguous"**, and goes on to list both lambdas as candidates.

I'm having difficulty understanding how the resolution is ambiguous to the compiler in one case (raw inheritance), and not in the other (using-declaration).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Fs>
struct S : Fs...
{
    S(Fs... funcs) : Fs(std::move(funcs))...
    {
    }

    using Fs::operator()...; // Removing this line breaks the code
};

auto main() -> int
{
    auto l1 = []() { return 0; };
    auto l2 = [](int i) { return i; };
    S s(l1, l2);
    std::cout << s(123)
              << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: For me it shows an Intellisense error, but compiles and runs successfully

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not).

Comment: The same thing happens when inheriting from non-lambda classes, so I'd be surprised if inheriting from lambdas (which are essentially syntactic sugar for anonymous classes) would behave differently.   You'll still get ambiguity if both the inherited `operator()` have the same signature.

Comment: Works fine for [clang and msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/MdnqPPsbc), though that doesn't necessarily mean they're correct.